# Expandable Listview Group Indicator half off screen?

Tags: java, android

I am using a custom Group indicator as shown in the code below. Now if I leave the default I can use setBounds perfectly, but when using my custom image which is the same dimensions and setup as the same .9 patch file it is always half off screen. No matter what values I use for setBounds()

```
            Drawable plus = (Drawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.expander_group);
            getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(plus);
            Display newDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            int width = newDisplay.getWidth();
            getExpandableListView().setIndicatorBounds(0,0);
```

XML expander_group

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_expanded="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/minus" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/plus" />
</selector>
```

EDIT:

Interestingly. I have copied the exact xml and image files from the standard Android files. And when I use the above method to define it the exact same thing happens! So it is not the xml or image files that are causing the issue I think.

[image]